# SEO best practices for image based web sites

Tags: seo, keywords, ranking, google-ranking, best-practices

How should I optimize an image based web site (art gallery, www.cavalet.bg ) to improve the SEO rank for a specific key word (in this case the bulgarian word for paintings - картини)?

The truth is I don't have any idea how could I add this word in the home page, if this would be the right solution. I have it just in the page title, page description, and the logo alt text. I use the word in question in the url for all categories too and in many articles in the blog pages.

What could be the best practices for image based web sites SEO optimisation?

Comment: I am not sure if this helps: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/63091/for-pages-with-one-painting-and-no-text-except-the-painting-name-media-used-and/63092#63092 (ignore the title). It is somewhat similar to what you are asking. Also keep in mind that it is bad to over optimize for one or a few keywords. Make sure you are using long-tail (ordinary day-to-day) search terms too. Image galleries are different of course, but search engines still want content and content is what drives search. BTW- I like your site. Good work!

Comment: Sorry but this question has been asked several times in various forms on Pro Webmasters. You will find additional questions and answers regarding rankings using the tag or search system.